# Using an IF statement within shortcode is breaking theme

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I've been setting up a slider shortcode with multiple options which is a caption, using metaboxes for the custom post type of slider to give options like, whether to show caption, caption text etc. Basically where I've used

```
if ( $captionCheckbox !== '1') {
```

to

```
    endif;

$slider .= '</li>';
```

Everything between the if and endif is breaking the theme but I cannot see why, here is the entire shortcode code if it helps.

```
function ls_slider_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

$slider = '<section id="slider" class="flexslider container clearfix">';

    $slider .= '<ul class="slides">';

        $sliderQuery = "post_type=slider";

        query_posts( $sliderQuery );


        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            $slideImage = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'slider');


            $slider .= '<li>';
                $slider .= $slideImage;

                $captionCheckbox = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'ls_show_slider_caption', true);
                $productCheckbox = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'ls_show_button_link', true);
                $position        = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'ls_caption_position', true);
                $heading         = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'ls_caption_heading', true);
                $text            = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'ls_caption_text', true);
                $productLink     = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'ls_project_link', true);

                    if ( $captionCheckbox !== '1' ) {

                        $slider .= '<div class="caption' . $position . '>';
                            $slider .= '<div class="body">';
                                $slider .= '<h2 class="caption-title">' . $heading . '</h2>';
                                $slider .= '<p>' . $text . '</p>';
                            $slider .= '</div>';

                            if ( $captionCheckbox !== '1' ) {
                                $slider .= '<a href="' . $productLink .'">View Project</a>';
                            }

                            endif;

                        $slider .= '</div>'
                    }

                    endif;

            $slider .= '</li>';

        endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();

    $slider .= '</ul>';

$slider .= '</section>';

return $slider;


}

add_shortcode('slider', 'ls_slider_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0):

In this form, you'll want to *either* use braces or open the block you intend to close with `endif` with a colon:

```
<?php if ( $captionCheckbox !== '1'): ?>

  // do stuff

<?php endif; ?>
```

If you use braces, the closing brace will suffice.

```
<?php if ( $captionCheckbox !== '1') { ?>

  // do stuff

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the reply. I'm not that knowledgable with php so I apologize for anything I'm missing. I think I've edited this correctly as to what you said but its not working still? I've answered below with the code due to character limit.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ls_slider_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

$slider = '<section id="slider" class="flexslider container clearfix">';

    $slider .= '<ul class="slides">';

        $sliderQuery = "post_type=slider";

        query_posts( $sliderQuery );


        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            $slideImage = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'slider');


            $slider .= '<li>';
                $slider .= $slideImage;

                $captionCheckbox = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'ls_show_slider_caption', true);
                $productCheckbox = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'ls_show_button_link', true);
                $position        = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'ls_caption_position', true);
                $heading         = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'ls_caption_heading', true);
                $text            = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'ls_caption_text', true);
                $productLink     = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'ls_project_link', true);

                    ?>

                    <?php if ( $captionCheckbox !== '1' ): ?>

                        <?php

                        $slider .= '<div class="caption' . $position . '>';
                            $slider .= '<div class="body">';
                                $slider .= '<h2 class="caption-title">' . $heading . '</h2>';
                                $slider .= '<p>' . $text . '</p>';
                            $slider .= '</div>';

                            ?>

                            <?php if ( $captionCheckbox !== '1' ): ?>
                                <?php $slider .= '<a href="' . $productLink .'">View Project</a>'; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>



                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php

                        $slider .= '</div>'

                        ?>


                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php

            $slider .= '</li>';

        endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();

    $slider .= '</ul>';

$slider .= '</section>';

return $slider;


}
```

Comment: I think there's an extra `endif` in there (two lines above where you close the slider `<li>`?)